# OData Post returns basic entity without navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a POST request I make to an OData controller that has navigation properties attached to the entity, and I would like all of these to be returned after the POST resolves. Instead, only the properties for the entity that have columns in the DB table that represents that entity are returned.

Here's the method I'm calling:

```
    // POST: odata/Links
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Link link)
    {
        link.ImageId = HelperModule.GetThumb(link.WebsiteUrl, 400, 300);
        link.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;

        db.Links.Add(link);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        /* now that we have the link saved to the database we need to add it to the attached views */
        foreach (BoardLink bl in link.BoardLinks)
        {
            bl.LinkId = link.LinkId;
            bl.IsActive = true;
            db.BoardLinks.Add(bl);
        }

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Created(link);
    }
```

Here's the entity:

```
public class Link
{
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public String ImageId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int LinkId { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String WebsiteUrl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Last modified time for this object.
    /// </summary>
    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public ICollection<LinkGradeLevel> LinkGradeLevels { get; set; }

    public ICollection<LinkCategory> LinkCategories { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<BoardLink> BoardLinks { get; set; } 
}
```

Here's the table for the entity:

[image: Link Table]

When I set a breakpoint on the return of the POST method I can see that it has LinkGradeLevels, LinkCategories, and BoardLinks set. These three aforementioned items are the navigation properties. I do have them configured in the edm model as you can see below:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  Creates the model for odata endpoints.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The IEdmModel for OData.</returns>
    private static IEdmModel GenerateEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Board>("boards");
        builder.EntitySet<BoardLink>("boardlinks");
        builder.EntitySet<Category>("categories");
        builder.EntitySet<GradeLevel>("gradelevels");
        builder.EntitySet<Link>("links");
        builder.EntitySet<LinkCategory>("linkcategories");
        builder.EntitySet<LinkGradeLevel>("linkgradelevels");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

When the link is returned to the client side it contains none of the navigation properties and only has CreatedOn, Description, ImageId, LinkId, Name, WebsiteUrl, and Timestamp. Why is this? Do I have to do something special to make it all return in a POST request?

---

**EDIT:** I do want to note that I've made the return type of the method a Link and that didn't work and returned what I've mentioned is already happening. I've also tried returning the following at the end of the current POST method I have:

```
return Ok(Link);
```

That also did not work, it just returned the same stuff that I've listed above.

Answer (score 1):

If you request data from the OData provider, you may include `$extend` to include referenced resources inline. This might be given implicit or explicit (see [`EnableQueryAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.enablequeryattribute.aspx)).

On POST data, according to the [OData specs](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/operations/#CreatingnewEntries), the server is "... sending the final state of the resource back to the client in the response." and "The Entry being created may contain Links to other Entries in the service."

I assume that Microsoft reads this as the information to be returned is only the object being created. To retrieve the full object again, you have to retrieve the data with GET again.

Comment: The specs make sense. That's a bummer though. Now I have to make an extra call if I want to stick to just OData.

I might just use a normal ApiController method instead for this to be more efficient.

Comment: You're talking like a GET that modifies data? I personally do not like going down that road.